# Want to display array without Brackets in csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, export, angular7

I want to display an array without commas when exporting in excel.

Please find the code

```js
var eventData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < callDetailsData.conditionalEvent.length; i++) {
  eventData.push(callDetailsData.conditionalEvent[i].conditionalEventName);
  console.log(eventData);
}

callPutResetExport.ConditionalEvent = eventData;
```

Here, I want to display `eventData` inside excel column without brackets. Currently I am getting o/p as

> [Stock price falling below falling threshold, Amount outstanding falling below threshold, Rating downgrade, Rating upgrade, Security cover falling below threshold]

but I want to remove those brackets display just the content.

Comment: Don't use `console.log` directly with an array. Consider converting the array to a string first (see `.join`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate you array into a string using `Array.prototype.join`

```
eventData = eventData.join(" ");
```

And it will appear out as a spaced string in the excel.

Comment: I want to remove the square bracket from o/p: [Stock price falling below falling threshold, Amount outstanding falling below threshold, Rating downgrade, Rating upgrade, Security cover falling below threshold]